# CSS & Javascript Manual Keyframe Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Say I have an animation defined in css like so:

```
@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        // effect here
    }

    ...

    100% {
        // effect here
    }
}
```

I can use it in a div like so:

```
#container {
    animation: my-animation 10s linear ;
}
```

Is there any way I can use javascript to programmatically set the percentage of the animation at any point instead? Something along the lines of:

```
function() {
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    while (some condition && container.percentage < 100) {
        container.percentage += 10;  // Here I would like to set the animation percentage to one of the percentages defined in the keyframe animation
    }
}
```

This is so I don't have to explicitly set the duration of the animation beforehand as it is unknown at runtime. I should add that I am aware that it currently is not possible to retrieve the percentage value of an animation but perhaps there is a way to manipulate it?

EDIT:
From what I understand from the comment by lupz:

```
.animation0 { /* 0% */

    }

.animation10 { /* 10% */

    }

...

.animation100 { /* 100% */

    }
```

Then I can change the class of the element to whichever percentage I need.

Comment: Maybe you could achieve your goal by using CSS classes instead of keyframes (percentages) and use the `transition` property to get it moving.

Comment: @lupz Thanks for the suggestion. See my edit ... is that what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the JS animation API - [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate), and then you can control the percentage (the `offset` property) directly via JS:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const animate = (offset = 1) => {
  const height = container.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  
  const animation = container.animate([
    {
      transform: 'translateY(0px)',
      offset: 0
    },
    {
      transform: `translateY(calc(100vh - ${height}px))`,
      offset
    }
  ], {
    duration: 1000,
  });
  
  if(offset > 0) {
    animation.finished
      .then(() => animate(offset - 0.1));
  }
};

animate();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where you have `if(offset) > 0 ...` could you possibly add an explanation of what that does and how I can use it to control the animation?

Comment: If the offset (equivalent to the percentage) is over 0, we wait for the current animation to end (`animation.finished` is a promise), and when it's done, we start the next iteration with a smaller offset (removing 10% - or 0.1 from the offset).

Comment: Makes perfect sense, now how would I reference the percentage to change outside of the animation function?

Comment: Use an external variable instead of passing it, to the next iteration.

Comment: Oh right, so instead of your if statement, I replace that with my code to increment the percentage?

Comment: This is the code to increment the `offset` - `offset - 0.1`. The if statement is a guard. The important thing here is that everything is controllable via JS.